# как узнать сгенерировалась таблица mysql

Tags: sql, sql-server

как узнать сгенерировалась таблица mysql
Изучаю my sql, написал код в MS Studis, вывод "Commands completed successfully."
Как посмотреть на сгенерированные таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это выглядит как Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, вряд ли там будет Mysql БД. Или таблица называется mysql? тогда исправлю теги на `sql-server`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правой кнопкой мыши по `Tables`, затем `Refresh`. Новые таблицы появятся в списке. То же самое работает с базами данных, колонками в таблицах и т.д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: хм, я так пробовал, у меня не появились
CREATE TABLE [GROUP] 
             ( 
                          group_code   INT NOT NULL, 
                          faculty_code INT NOT NULL, 
                          group_name   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
                          CONSTRAINT [PK_GROUP] PRIMARY KEY clustered ( [group_code] asc ) WITH (ignore_dup_key = off)
             ) 
             go 
CREATE TABLE [Personal_card] ......
Это правильный код для создания?

Comment: Забавна, через ф5 не создавалось
А через кнопку "execute" создалось

Comment: возможно, использовалась другая база. лучше включать USE [mydbname] в начале скрипта